# Limit impoly clicks and convert it to a rectangle - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using impoly as in the script below and I have two questions:

- Can I limit the to points clicked (e.g., 5) and close it automatically?
- Is there a way convert the impoly to imrect like in the attached image (red box)?

Script:

```
clc;
clear; 

figure, imshow('pout.tif');
hpoly = impoly(gca);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of impoly, I don't think it is directly possible. For such custom behaviour, you should probably write your own point picking function.

Several matlab functio ncan help you in this direction.

- `[x,y] = ginput(n)` to pick points
- `impoint(hparent,x, y)` to draw draggable points,
- `line` to draw a the line between points, and the rectangle bounding box.

`impoint` has a `'PositionConstraintFcn'` parameter, that will call a function of yours when the point is moved. You can use it to  update the lines draw when the points are moved.

I suggest you to have a main function that handles the point picking (constraining the number of points, etc...), and a "display" function, that calculate the bounding box, draw the lines between points, that you can call when a point is added (in the main function), or when a point is moved (with the `'PositionConstraintFcn'`parameter).